# Laravel 6.x VerifiesEmails.php fails with $request->route('hash'), passes with $request->get('hash')

Tags: php, laravel, email-verification

In `\Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\VerifiesEmails.php`, line 39 fails with `$request->route('hash')`, but passes with `$request->get('hash')`. I am not sure if this is a bug, but I see nothing I have done that would somehow break this function specifically right here. I have not modified my `VerificationController.php` file from the core either.

The `$request->route('id')` above works, but the passed ID in this route is not a parameter, but directly in the path whereas the hash is affixed as ?hash=myhash.

For reference, here is my URL: `http://localhost:8000/email/verify/8edd16a5-ad04-4782-b0fe-33f0f482d080?expires=myexpiryhere&hash=myhashhere&signature=mysignaturehere`

Can anyone explain to me how to get this working? Obviously modifying the vendor files is not an option. I posted this in the Laravel issues [here](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/30240), but was directed out with the suggestion that maybe I forgot a route parameter. The URL is generated by the framework, so I've no idea what parameter I could be forgetting.

Comment: Can you show your routes registration?

Comment: Posted an answer below, that was the problem. Thank you for asking the right question! Will keep this up in case anyone has the same problem down the road.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is my bad, but thanks to Chin Leung for asking the right question.

My current routes are:

```
Route::get('email/verify', [VerificationController::class, 'show'])->name('verification.notice');
Route::get('email/verify/{id}', [VerificationController::class, 'verify'])->name('verification.verify');
Route::post('email/resend', [VerificationController::class, 'resend'])->name('verification.resend');
```

I specify them myself because I do not use the default namespacing in my routes files, I import the controllers directly to make refactoring easier. It looks like a new param was added to the `verification.verify` route later on, so it should now be `email/verify/{id}/{hash}`